# How to download files from Firebase storage

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, google-cloud-storage

I've being trying to download some files from Firebase storage. Right now I am trying listing all the files in a specific path like this:

```
from google.cloud import storage


client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('myapp.appspot.com/path/to/folder')
blob = list(bucket.list_blobs())
print(len(blob))
```

The problem I am seeing is that I am getting all the results that are on my bucket and I only need the ones on the path I selected.

What am I doing wrong? Is there other way tho achieve what I need?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try :

```
 from google.cloud import storage
 from google.cloud.storage import Blob  
 storage_client = storage.Client()

 # get all the buckets
 buckets = storage_client.list_buckets()
 for bucket in buckets:
     print(bucket.name)
 # output  bucket_name

 # get all the blobs in a bucket
 bucket = client.get_bucket("bucket_name")
 blobs = list(bucket.list_blobs())
 for blob in blobs:
     print (blob)
 # print the blobs: blob_name

 #check if the blob exists
 assert isinstance(bucket.get_blob('blob_name'), Blob)

 #get the blob from path
 my_blob = Blob.from_string("gs://bucket_name/blob_name")

 # List the files in a folder 
 files = bucket.list_blobs(prefix='folder_name')
 for f in files:
     print(f.name)
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me clarify some things up

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the bucket name is just "myapp.appspot.com".  There are no path components to Cloud Storage bucket names.  A bucket doesn't contain other buckets, just files with different paths.  You will want to take the path out of the bucket name and instead feed that string to the [list API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects) to get the files with specified prefix.